How to fix cannot call a class as a function using withRouter React native
I have a render error that says "Cannot call a class as a function" This error occurred after I upgraded my react-native-meteor to @meteorrn/core
Index.js:
import RenderMixin from './page.render';
import MethodMixin from './page.method';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import Meteor, {withTracker} from '@meteorrn/core';
import {setJobQuery} from '@api/jobs/reducers/actions-reducer';
import moment from 'moment';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';


const Page = MethodMixin(RenderMixin);

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    jobQuery: state.jobQuery,
    userProfile: state.userProfile,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    setJobQuery: params => dispatch(setJobQuery(params)),
    dispatch,
  };
};

const container = withTracker(props => {
  const lng = props.userProfile.language.toLowerCase();

  const userSub = Meteor.subscribe('user.data');
  const user = Meteor.user() || {};

  const {keyword, limit, date, filterDate} = props.jobQuery;

  const listSubs = Meteor.subscribe(
    'get.truck.dispatch.list',
    keyword,
    date,
    limit,
    lng,
  );

  // console.log(filterDate,"filterdate")
  // console.log(moment(filterDate).startOf('day').add(1,'day'),"start")
  // console.log(moment(filterDate).endOf('day').toDate(),"end")

  const today = moment.utc(filterDate).startOf('day').add(1,'day')
  const tom = moment.utc(filterDate).endOf('day').toDate()

  console.log(moment.utc(filterDate).toISOString(),"start")
  console.log(moment.utc(filterDate).endOf('day'),"enddd")

  const tra = AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
  .then((keys)=> AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys)
                  .then((data) => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))));

  console.log(tra)
  
  console.log(date)

  const xxx = Meteor.Collection('dispatch').find(
    {
      $or: [{'dispatch.truckId': user.profile?.truckerId}, {'dispatch.driverId': user.profile?.truckerId}],
      'dispatch.dateCreated': {$gte: today, $lte: tom}
      
    },
    {sort: {orderDateObject: -1}},
    // {fields: {
    //   'dispatch.dateCreated': 1
    // }}
  ) || []

  // dispatchData.customerName = job?.[0]?.customerName || job?.customerName;
  // const yyyy = xxx.map(x => x.dispatch.dateCreated)
  // console.log(JSON.stringify(yyyy, null, 2))

  return {
    user,
    userSubReady: userSub.ready(),
    listSubs: !listSubs.ready(),
    list:xxx,
    date,
    lng
  };
})(Page);

const PageRedux = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(container);

export default withRouter(PageRedux);

Page Render.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Drawer from 'react-native-drawer';
import DefaultDrawer from '@component/default-drawer.js';

class Page extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer
        openDrawerOffset={0.2}
        ref={ref => (this._drawer = ref)}
        content={
          <DefaultDrawer closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer} {...this.props} />
        }>
        
      </Drawer>
    );
  }

 
}

export default Page;


